# Cannot resolve .andExpect() method even after implementing Stackoverflow answer

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am aware a question with the exact same title exists but the answer doesn't help me any further.

I am using WebMvcTest to test my controller class. However when it comes to comparing the result using .andExpect, my IDEA (intellij) can't resolve it.

The question with the same title as this one's solution is included in my imports and is unused. I also looked at the spring docs and used the 2 implements needed.

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
```

Below you will find my entire class and in this case all my imports.

```
package be.pxl.backend.restapi;

import be.pxl.backend.restapi.controller.UserController;
import be.pxl.backend.restapi.domain.User;
import be.pxl.backend.restapi.manager.UserManager;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

//stackoverflow try == unused
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserManager userManager;

    @Test
    public void givenUser_WhenGetUser_ThenReturnUser() throws Exception{
        User bjorn = new User();
        bjorn.setUsername("Bjorn");
        bjorn.setPassword("Wachtwoord");
        bjorn.setEmail("test@email.be");

        given(userManager.getUserById(1L)).willReturn(bjorn);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/user/1")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].username", is(bjorn.getUsername()))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, according to the Checkstyle, you should [avoid star imports](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#AvoidStarImport).
Secondly, you have misplaced two closing parentheses, one in `contentType()`  and the other one in the last call of `andExpect()`. Below is a working code.

**imports:**

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import be.pxl.backend.restapi.controller.UserController;
import be.pxl.backend.restapi.domain.User;
import be.pxl.backend.restapi.manager.UserManager;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
```

Note the imports are ordered as per [Google Java Style](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s3.3.3-import-ordering-and-spacing).

**mock test:**

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/user/1")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].username", is(bjorn.getUsername())));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer provided. This is a pretty stupid mistake I admit but shouldn't intellij have given a parenthesis error like it normally does.

Thanks again, great reminder to take some more time and count my parentheses!